# How do you use code fragment mode in the Intellij debugger?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the debugger, you can press alt-f8 and evaluate an expression.

There's also a code fragment mode. The documentation in IntelliJ only says:

> Code Fragment Mode for evaluating short code portions introducing them
>   in the Statements to evaluate text field. Supported constructs are
>   declarations, assignments, loops and if/else.

I can't find any examples on the web of how to use it and can't figure out myself.

Can you give examples of how to use the supported constructs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

```
public class CodeFragment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        list.add(new Foo("555"));
        list.add(new Foo("777"));
        list.add(new Foo("999"));
        list.add(new Foo("bill"));

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static class Foo {
        String s;

        public Foo(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }
}
```

If we set a break point on the println, we can put the following into the code fragment

```
Foo resultFoo = null;
Iterator<Foo> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Foo foo = it.next();
    if (foo.s.equals("777")) {
        resultFoo = foo;
    }
}
resultFoo = resultFoo;
```

This demonstrates declaration, assignment, a loop, and an if.

Note that the foreach loop is not supported, in older versions of intellij!

Also note the assignment at the end. As far as I can tell, the result that gets displayed is the result of the last statement. Without that last statement, this code would display 'false' - ie the result of the last call to it.next.